# How do i detect the control that sent the WM_KEYDOWN?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, focus

[`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message sends the message to the main window, I'd like to get control that originated the message. I've tried with [`GetFocus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getfocus) handling [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) like below but it didn't do anything, even when a press a key with focus on the buttona. How is that done? what am I missing?

Here's how I'm handling WM_KEYDOWN:

```
 case WM_KEYDOWN:
    HWND hFocus = GetFocus();
    if(hFocus == buttonA)
    {
        buttona_onKeyDown();
    }
    else if(hFocus == buttonB)
    {
        buttonb_onKeyDown();
    }
    else
    {
        //MessageBox(NULL, L"Not found!", L"", MB_OK);
    }
 break;
```

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void buttona_onKeyDown();
void buttonb_onKeyDown();

HWND buttonA, buttonB;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Buttons";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    HWND hWnd =
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Buttons",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  150, 150, 300, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    switch(msg)
    {

        case WM_CREATE:
            buttonA =
            CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"A",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                20, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 10, NULL, NULL);

            buttonB =
            CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"B",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                120, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 11, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

         case WM_KEYDOWN:
            HWND hFocus = GetFocus();
            if(hFocus == buttonA)
            {
                buttona_onKeyDown();
            }
            else if(hFocus == buttonB)
            {
                buttonb_onKeyDown();
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox(NULL, L"Not found!", L"", MB_OK);
            }
         break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void buttona_onKeyDown()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"A OnKeyDown", L"", MB_OK);
}

void buttonb_onKeyDown()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"B OnKeyDown", L"", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN` is **posted** by the system in response to keyboard input. It doesn't originate from a control.

Comment: @IInspectable but let's say the user has focus on button and did press down a key, how do I detect that?

Comment: Subclass your button control, and handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) appropriately. Now you can handle `WM_KEYDOWN` messages in your subclassed button control.

Comment: @IInspectable implemented that, perfect, thanks! post it as answer so I can accept

Comment: In addition to subclassing, I think you can use `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and call `GetFocus` in the hook function to get the focused window.

Comment: I don't think I need that anymore, I initially was using GetFocus() in order to retrieve the control that the user was typing (generating the WM_KEYDOW) but after subclassing, I know right away which control "generated" the WM_KEYDOWN message. Is that right or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right.